# Can't hide last visible link in vertical block with overflow: hidden

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

Can't hide last visible link in vertical block with overflow: hidden... Browser cut last link, I need hide it.

So, see the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/otF5r.png

gray border are current border of fix-height element and list of links dynamically generated and last link not really last, some count of links are hidden.

I'm use something like this:

```
<ul class="b-gid">
  <? if ($_GET['page'] == 1) { ?>
    <li><h2>Gid</h2></li>
    <li><a class="b-news__item__link" href="url1">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a class="b-news__item__link" href="url2">Link2</a></li>
...
    <li><a class="b-news__item__link" href="urlN">Link2</a></li>
  <? } ?>
</ul>

<style>
    .b-gid {
        width: 214px;
        float: right;
        border: 3px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 19px;
        padding: 15px;
        list-style: none;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .b-gid a {
        color: #48a59a;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>

<script>        
  $(function(){         
    $('.b-gid').first().css('height',$('.post').first().height() - $('.b-services').first().height() - 125 + 'px');});
</script>
```

Comment: it is good to post your code

Comment: something like this
 <ul>
 <li>
 <a>some link</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 

 ul {
 width: 214px;
 float: right;
 border: 3px solid #ddd;
 padding: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: without a height, how would `.b-gid` know when to start hiding overflow? considering making a JS fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: sorry, some js calc it's height, i'm add it to my question